Laravel 9, a specific cookie gets immediately deleted right after i create it
We are trying to build a filter system for a list of wines, so we built a step-by-step wizard to set the right filtering.
In order to do so, inside the controller that effectively filters wines called WineController, we check the presence of a cookie and then proceed with the query.
The problem is that only a specific cookie gets immediately deleted right after the creation (locally it works, online not). We tried different approach to correctly save and retrieve this cookie, we used both laravel cookie and php cookie, we also tried using laravel session (this was the first idea, but this specific variable gets ignored).
Right now, we are using Laravel 9, this is the query that effectively filters wines inside the WineController
//WineController

/*other code*/

if ( Session::has("regione") || Cookie::has("regione") || isset($_COOKIE['regione']) ) {
                if(Cookie::has("regione"))
                    $cookie = Cookie::get("regione");

                if(isset($_COOKIE['regione']))
                    $cookie = $_COOKIE['regione'];

                $wines = (Session::has("regione")) ? $wines->where("regione", Session::get("regione") ) : $wines->where("regione", $cookie );
                $regionearray[] = Session::has("regione") ? Session::get("regione") : $cookie;
            }

/*other code*/

We used this particularly intricate IF because, in production, the session variable "regione" doesen't gets recognized, the same with laravel cookie, the only variable that has this odd behavior is "regione".
In the WizardController this is how we set it
//WizardController

$session = Session::put('regione', $regioni);
$cookie = Cookie::queue(Cookie::make('regione', $regioni, 1440));
setcookie('regione', $regioni, time()+1440, '/');

if(!isset($cookie) || !isset($_COOKIE['regione'])) {
            $data = [
                "user" => $user,
                "slug" => $slug,
                "tipologie" => $tipologie
            ];
        } else{
            $data = [
                "user" => $user,
                "slug" => $slug,
                "tipologie" => $tipologie,
                "cookie" => $cookie
            ];
        }

        return $data;

so the strange thing is that only this variable has this behavior, other cookies and session variables work correctly.
As said before this works great locally and on a testing domain, but on the production one not.
Sorry for bad english and/or bad explaination of the problem.
Thank you for your help.
